# Is it possible to to retrieve a top ROW_NUMBER() for each group without a sub-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

In the spirit of succinct and beautiful coding, I am wondering if anyone has been able to create a query that performs exactly as below, **but with no sub-queries**.

### Example query:

Essentially, the sub-query is retrieving the most recent date for each user by first ordering and labeling each row for each patient where "1" is the most recent date for each patient. The outer query then identifies and returns each "1" which is the max date associated with each user.

```
SELECT user_name
      ,date
FROM(
    SELECT user_name
          ,date
          ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY date DESC) as row_num
    FROM yourtable
) AS t
WHERE t.row_num = 1
```

### Data example pre-execution:

```
|user_name|date |
|Some1    |10/22|
|Some1    |10/27|
|Some1    |10/30|
|Some2    |10/30|
|Some2    |11/15|
|Some2    |11/18|
```

### Data example post-execution:

```
|user_name|date |
|Some1    |10/30|
|Some2    |11/18|
```

*Preparing to have my mind blown by you all*

Comment: Why do you specifically want to avoid a subquery? Alternatives might not perform as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you can use `group by`:

```
select user_name, max(date)
from t
group by user_name;
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity and efficiency of this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WITH TIES` option

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  yourtable
 Order By row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY date DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `SELECT DISTINCT`, `LAST_VALUE`, and `MAX() OVER` (specifying `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`).  Something like this

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTable;
go
create table #tTable(
  user_name     varchar(100) not null,
  dt            date not null);
 
 Insert into #tTable values
('Some1', '20201022'),
('Some1', '20201027'),
('Some1', '20201030'),
('Some2', '20201030'),
('Some2', '20201115'),
('Some2', '20201118');
```

Query

```
select distinct last_value(user_name) over (partition by user_name order by dt) as user_name,
                max(dt) over (partition by user_name order by dt 
                              rows between unbounded preceding
                                   and unbounded following) as [date]
from #tTable;
```

Output

```
user_name   date
Some1       2020-10-30
Some2       2020-11-18
```